# 3D mapping with Hokuyo and Kinect

Tags: kinect

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi! I'm a begginer using Gazebo and I'm getting completely lost with all the documentation.

I'm triying to do a very simple thing. I want to mount a Hokuyo laser sensor in a vehicle, turned 90 degrees so it detects a vertical plane, and then move the vehicle forward to do a 3D reconstruction of what the Hokuyo is detecting.

The perfect set would be to have a window in which the vehicle can be seen moving parallel to a certain structure and then other window where the stucture is been reconstructed as the vehicle passes by.

Any idea of how can I do this the simplest way? I only need it for visualization, I don't need to do anithing with the data afterwards.

Also, I need to do the same with a kinect sensor.

I'm using ROS Kinetic with Gazebo 7 in Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16864/3d-mapping-with-hokuyo-and-kinect/) by [Burgos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3649/burgos/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi @burgos ,

It's a good idea to break the project into small tasks not to get overwhelmed trying to do everything at once.

To start with, you could go through the [beginner tutorial series](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_b&tut=guided_b1) where you'll start getting familiar with Gazebo concepts and build a vehicle with a depth camera mounted on it. Conveniently, this is very similar to your use case!

After you've grasped this part, you could look into controlling the robot with ROS instead of a Gazebo plugin, [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#DifferentialDrive) tutorial should help.

Good luck, and be sure to ask more questions if you get stuck. The more specific your question is, the higher the chance you'll get an answer straight away ;)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Burgos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3649/burgos/) on 2017-07-28**:
Thanks @chapulina!

I've advanced a little bit since I posted this question, now I'm stuck in other thing. I've followed this two tutorials:
http://moorerobots.com/blog/post/1
http://moorerobots.com/blog/post/2

Now my problem is that I can't turn the Hokuyo so it faces to a side of the vehicle vertically.
I've tried to change the  parameters of the Hokuyo set in mybot_ws/src/mybot_description/urdf/mybot.gazebo, but it doesn't seem to make the LIDAR move in any way...

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-07-28**:
Are you trying to change the way the sensor is attached to the robot, or to move it while the robot is moving? Maybe you can ask a new question detailing your current situation and what you've already tried ;)

**Comment by [Burgos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3649/burgos/) on 2017-07-28**:
I need it to stay put in the robot when it moves, but i need to detect a vertical plane instead of an horizontal one, that is why I need it to be turned.
I know, I should open other question. I'll see if I can do it for myself first and if I get stuck I'll open that new question.

Thanks again @chapulina! ;D